# « L'échapper belle » : de quoi s'agit-il ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

D'où vient l'expression « on l'a échappé belle » ? Quel est le sens du mot « bel » dans cette expression ? Est-ce qu'« échappé » est un nom ou un verbe dans ce cas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans cette expression, *échapper* est bien un verbe, et on retrouve l'expression *l'échapper belle* dans sa [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9chapper).

L'[étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9chapper) d'*échapper* trace l'origine de l'expression à 1640, sans vraiment expliquer le rôle de *belle* dans l'expression. Une [autre réponse](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/l-echapper-belle.php) indique que *bel(le)* signifiait à l'époque *bien*.

Comment: belle et bien trouvée, cette relation entre bel et bien !

Answer (score 7):

Le *[Dictionnaire historique de la langue Française](http://www.lerobert-historique.com/)* comme le *[Dictionnaire culturel en langue française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence:Dictionnaire_culturel_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)*<sup>1</sup> donnent comme origine de la locution  « *l'échapper belle* » :

> « manquer une balle qui était belle, c'est à dire rattrapable ».

Pas de précision sur de quelle sorte de balle il s'agit, mais on peut penser, vu la date de 1640 qui est donnée, au jeu de paume, ancêtre du tennis et qui était pratiqué dès le XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle.

De nos jours la locution veut dire *échapper de justesse à un danger*.

- *Je l'ai échappé belle* : c'est le verbe *échapper*.
- *Quelle belle échappée !* :  il s'agit du nom *échappée* (f.) (qui vient du verbe *échapper*).

Il y a un film qui s'appelle *[L'échappée belle](http://www.premiere.fr/film/L-Echappee-Belle-147038)* où l'expression est employée avec son sens propre (*le fait d'échapper de justesse*) et une émission de télévision *[Échappées belles](http://www.france5.fr/echappees-belles/videos/)* ou l'expression est employée au sens figuré, et où *échappée* à le sens d'"escapade", de "voyage" et il y est question de "beaux voyages".

---

<sup>1</sup>Dirigés par Alain Rey.