# Utilisation du verbe « bailler »

Tags: usage, vocabulaire

Une [question posée récemment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/lechapper-belle-de-quoi-sagit-il) m'a fait penser à l'expression *Vous me la baillez belle*.
(->*Vous m'en racontez une bien bonne/je ne vous crois pas*)

Le verbe *bailler* est-il employé de nos jours autrement que dans l'expression *la bailler belle*  ?

Comment: Et en recherchant un peu je me suis rendu compte des homophones :
*baîller* ; *bailler*, *bayer*.  Bien compliqué pour un non francophone !

Comment: Il y a pas mal d'expressions sur le site du [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/) pour [bailler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bailler), [bâiller](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2iller) et [bayer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bayer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je ne sais pas en français pour sûr, mais en picard qui est assez similaire, et par d'où je viens, « bailler » veut dire « donner », donc « vous me la donnez belle » vous m'en racontez une belle ?

**Ajout:** Ma grand-mère dit « Qu'est ce que tu me bailles ? » pour « Qu'est-ce que tu me racontes ? ». Je pense que c'est assez similaire.

Comment: Et *bailler*  est-il encore utilisé en Picard dans d'autres cas que pour *dire des paroles mensongères/qu'on ne croit pas* ?

Comment: Dans le sens ou il est utilise, c'est normalement pour souligner un doute sur la veracite de ce que la personne a dit. Je pense que ce mot se retrouve dans tous les patois du nord de la France.

Answer (score 5):

Les dérivés [bail](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bail) et [bailleur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bailleur) sont encore couramment utilisés, dans le domaine de la location de biens immobiliers par exemple.

Answer (score 3):

Il m'arrive de dire « peux-tu me bailler 10 euros, » mais j'avoue que je ne l'ai jamais entendu dire par d'autres que moi :)
(Ah, et je choisis bien des gens qui comprendraient le mot…)

Answer (score 1):

[J'allais mettre le suivant en haut comme "Comment" mais j'ai pas assez de "Réputation" pour faire ça (ni grande chose a perdre!) donc le voila:]

Désolé, je n’ai rien a ajouter point vue réponse, sauf peut-être « donner/**bailler une claque** », mais en pensant sur des homophones dont vous parliez je me suis mis (a boire?, non) a faire la phrase suivante:

Attention !  Même si ça fait un bail que je n’ai pas pensé aux « beaux baux » que vous m’avez fait, c’est toujours facile à savoir quand vous me la baillez belle car a chaque fois âpres vous bâillez à t’en décrocher la mâchoire en bayant aux corneilles!

In spite of all the grammar faults that my "work" surely contains, I hope that it makes at least some sense in a funny little way.  Anyway, it certainly proves your point that non francophones , or at least this one, find all of this very complicated!

Bail Bail!